# Latex format in comments on iOS app Stack Exchange

Tags: support, feature-request, comment

I can't correctly view formulas in comments on SE app for iOS. I've an iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.3.

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

Answer (score 4):

There is an indirect way. If you tap the comment, a little white bar should roll out underneath, which has a button titled "$\color{red}{\cdots \text{more}}$". Hit this button and then hit the "$\color{blue}{\text{Render Mathjax}}$" button. A new screen should open with the Mathjax rendered.

[image]

Comment: The same kind of menu selection is necessary on the Android SE App, in order to render $\LaTeX$ in Comments.